# PSR-7 validation with regex possible? (parameter clash)

Tags: php, symfony, openapi, nelmioapidocbundle, psr-7

I'm currently generating OpenAPI annotations via Symfony (5.1) Routes and NelmioApiDocBundle,

One of the routes looks like this:

```
 * @Route("/users/{id}", methods={"GET"}, requirements={"id": "\d+"})
 * @OA\Parameter(name="id", in="path", description="The id of the user", required=true, @OA\Schema(type="integer"))
```

and another like

```
 * @Route("/users/followed", methods={"GET"})
```

I'm using the League's OpenAPI PSR-7 Message Validator (https://github.com/thephpleague/openapi-psr7-validator) by converting the Symfony Request to a PSR-7 Request with `symfony/psr-http-message-bridge` and `nyholm/psr7`. It all works well, except for those 2 endpoints. I keep getting

`The given request matched these operations: [/api/users/{id},get],[/api/charter-calculations/followed,get]. However, it matched not a single schema of theirs.`

Is it possible the `/followed` can only be matched against `/{id}`? and thus the validator gets confused? Or is a regex for `{id}` as I have already done possible?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, so answering myself. It was somewhat specific to my problem, but possibly helpful for other people.

I had additional parameters such as

```
* @OA\Parameter(name="pageSize", in="query", @OA\Schema(type="integer"))
```

When I unit tested some of the validations to trigger an error (e.g. `pageSize=test`), it would throw a `League\OpenAPIValidation\PSR7\Exception\Validation\InvalidQueryArgs`.

But when I added the `"/users/followed"` endpoint then the previous tests would throw a different error: `League\OpenAPIValidation\PSR7\Exception\MultipleOperationsMismatchForRequest`, because now the error isn't "Hey, I found the endpoint, but the query is wrong!" but rather "Hey, I found multiple possible endpoints, they're all wrong!".